# mysql опасность strict mode

Tags: mysql

В чем может быть опасность строгого режима для mysql (strict mode)?
Всё что получилось мне найти, это, что могут сохранится данные не в том, виде, в котором ожидаю и я об этом не узнаю. К примеру varchar(5) обрежет текст "Привет, это я", до "Приве".

Comment: Всё с точностью до наоборот, strict mode защищает от такой обрезки, он безопасен и его нужно использовать

Comment: Я это и имел в виду, что если strict mode, то он выдаст ошибку и откатит транзакцию, если не он, то обрежется